# Windows "more" command with \q doesn't work

Tags: windows, attributes, command

Windows command more seems to work great except with help switch?  Is this right?  Is there a way to pause at the bottom of the screen?

For example    `netstat \q | more`

this doesn't pause it...am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipe operator only affects the standard output stream; help text is often sent to the standard error stream instead.

This will work:

```
netstat -? 2>&1 | more
```

The `2>&1` redirects the standard error stream to the standard output stream so that it can be affected by the pipe operator.

Comment: You the man, that did it - yes it's on my Windows 10 \q gives me the help and /q gives the connections.  You're answer works great for both!!!

Comment: Preferable to use `-?` or `/?` I think, more conventional and less likely to stop working in future releases.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want `netstat /q | more` with a forward slash instead.

Comment: Makes no difference, since there isn't a `q` option in the first place. :-)

Comment: It's on my machine. Maybe it's new to Windows 10. "-q Displays all connections, listening ports, and bound nonlistening TCP ports. Bound nonlistening ports may or may not be associated with an active connection."

Comment: Ah, yes, you're quite right.  I *think* the OP actually wants the help text, rather than the `/q` option, but it isn't entirely clear.